# I have to have lots of fields in Django models i just want to know is it a proper way to do in the below way ? if not what can I do

Tags: python, django-models

```
class AboutUs(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='aboutus/image')
    main_definition = models.TextField()
    sub_def_1_header = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_def_1 = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_def_2_header = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_def_2 = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_sub_def_1_header = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_sub_def_1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_sub_def_2_header = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_sub_def_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_sub_def_3_header = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_sub_def_3 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_sub_sub_def_1_header = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_sub_sub_def_1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_sub_sub_def_2_header = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_sub_sub_def_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_sub_sub_def_3_header = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_sub_sub_def_3 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_sub_sub_def_4_header = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_sub_sub_def_4 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    curent_info = models.BooleanField(default=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f" {self.main_definition[:30]}  /  {self.sub_sub_def_1_header[:20]} "
```

is it a good way to have mane field in Django models or there is a beter and more sensible way to do it ?

Comment: If you need all the fields in a single table, then this is the way. If data are independent, seperate into multiple models based on dependencies. Otherwise just leave some spaces in between so it would look better

Answer (score 0):

Once you have completed the database design process and considered the relationships among models, avoided redundant data, and followed best practices, having multiple fields in a table is not necessarily a problem. It is important to ensure that the design is well-thought-out and meets the requirements of your application.

for the above example, you can also utilize the JSONField from Django, which allows for storing JSON data in the database. This field can be useful when dealing with flexible and dynamic data structures. You can refer to the Django documentation for more information on how to use the JSONField: [Django JSONField Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield)

Check once if the database you are using is compatible with JSONField or not from the above link. If your database does not support JSONField, using multiple fields in a table can still be a valid approach to store the required data.

Ultimately, the decision on whether to use a JSONField or multiple fields depends on your specific use case and the nature of the data you are working with